# Effect of adding a zero row and column on the eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Suppose I have a matrix, and for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, I insert a row of zeros between the $n$th and $n+1$th rows, and a column of zeroes between the $n$th and $n+1$the columns. For example, for $n=1$ and the matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
5&7&9 \\
7&1&1 \\
9&1&3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I would obtain:
$$B=\begin{bmatrix}
5&0&7&9 \\
0&0&0&0 \\
7&0&1&1 \\
9&0&1&3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
In general, what effect does this have on the eigenvalues? If we subtract $\lambda I$ and cofactor expand along the zero row or zero column of a matrix transformed in this way, clearly zero must be an eigenvalue. From this, and playing around with some matrices, I believe the following:

**If $A$ is a singular matrix, then the eigenvalues of $B$ are the same as the eigenvalues of $A$. If $A$ is an invertible matrix, then the eigenvalues of $B$ are the eigenvalues of $A$ as well as 0.**

Is this claim true, and how would I prove it if so?

Comment: *Hint*: with a permutation you can always suppose the row and column you add are the first

Comment: If you desire the eigenvalues of $B$, calculate the characteristic polynomial $\det(B-\lambda I)$ by cofactor expansion on one of the zero rows or columns. The only term that will survive is $\lambda\det(A-\lambda I)$. From what I can see,  it's clear that your statement holds in the both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far as I can tell, the comment by superckl is exactly what I need (thanks by the way!). Subtracting $\lambda I$ and cofactor expanding along the zero row or column yields:
$$ \pm\lambda\det(A-\lambda I)=\det(B-\lambda I)=0 $$
Clearly, $\lambda=0$ must be a solution. That's as far as I got when I posted the question. But as superckl pointed out, if we suppose now that $\lambda\neq0$ to get the other eigenvalues, we see that:
$$\det(A-\lambda I)=0$$
and so since $\lambda$ was an arbitrary nonzero eigenvalue of $B$, the remaining eigenvalues are the same.

Answer (score 5):

You can transform matrix by permuting columns and rows of a new matrix to the matrix where zero columns and rows are for example in the first column and row. So you have then a diagonal block matrix when one of the block is old matrix and other is zero  ...

Comment: For determinant of block diagonal matrix see https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Determinant_of_Block_Diagonal_Matrix

Comment: For the case see also  permutations in action:  
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0 \\
1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
5&0&7&9 \\
0&0&0&0 \\
7&0&1&1 \\
9&0&1&3 \\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0&0 \\
1&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&0 \\
0&0&0&1 \\
\end{bmatrix}  =\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0 \\
0&5&7&9 \\
0&7&1&1 \\
0&9&1&3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$